# javascript File to post function with $http angular service and web-api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, asp.net-web-api

I want to upload `javascript file`or basically transmit a `javascript file` to post function, on client side I've used `angularjs` `$http` `service` to send data to client as shown below:

```
$http({    
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/api/fileupload",
                    data: JSON.stringify(scope.c.model),//scope.c.model is  javascript File
                    contentType: "application/json"

                }).then(successResponse => {
                    this.scope["text"] = "Succes...";
                }, errorResponse=> {
                    this.scope["text"] = "Error...";
                });
```

and here is `web-api` `controller`

```
    public void Post(HttpPostedFile file)
{
    //do stuff...  
}
```

file is null but scope.c.model is filled with correct data.  if I change the Type of data  is transmitted to an array (for example), everything is fine..It seems that the post method does not recognize the file. 

seocnd below way also does not work, `file.count` is zero.

```
public void Post()//HttpPostedFile file)
    {
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
             //do stuff...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for the problem..with code below I am totally able to save any file locally or on server. 

**client side**

`scope.c.model` is the type of `Javascript FILE API`. behind the scene is the `model` which is like this `ng-model = model` , `c` is controller and becasue this code is in link function of my directive I can access the model trough `scope.c.model` . `model` here could be any name. 
as I want to read the `File` I should use `FileReader`.

```
            scope.$watch('c.model', () => {
            if (scope.c.model != null) {

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = () => {
                    var base64 = reader.result.split("base64,")[1];
                    var file =
                    {
                        content: base64,
                        name: scope.c.model.name,
                        type: scope.c.model.type,
                        size: scope.c.model.size
                        };
                    var t = file.content;
                    $http({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "/api/fileupload",//web-api contorller
                        data: file,// scope.c.model is javascript File
                        contentType: "application/octet-stream"

                    }).then(successResponse => {
                        this.scope["text"] = "Succes...";
                    }, errorResponse=> {
                        this.scope["text"] = "Error...";
                    });
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(scope.c.model);             
            }
        });
```

**server side**

```
public class File
{
    public string Content;
    public string Name;
    public string Type;
    public string Size;
}
public class FileUploadController : ApiController
{
    public void Post(File file)
    {
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(file.Content);
        using (var imageFile = new FileStream(@"C:\fileupload\"+file.Name + ".jpg", FileMode.Create))
        {
            imageFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            imageFile.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```